# How does scikitlearn implement line search?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn

In [this section](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/ensemble.html#mathematical-formulation) of the documentation on gradient boosting, it says

> Gradient Boosting attempts to solve this minimization problem numerically via steepest descent: The steepest descent direction is the negative gradient of the loss function evaluated at the current model F_{m-1} which can be calculated for any differentiable loss function:

[image]

> Where the step length \gamma_m is chosen using line search:

[image]

I understand the purpose of the line search, but I don't understand the algorithm itself. I read through the [source code](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/b7e3702/sklearn/ensemble/gradient_boosting.py), but it's still not clicking. An explanation would be much appreciated.

Comment: Your question is more about the Gradient Boosting algorithm itself or the sklearn implementation? You can go through the wekipedia introduction(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient_boosting)  for more details about the algorithm.

Comment: @hsc It would've been more useful if you have referenced the [wikipedia article on Line Search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_search).  I have already read both articles multiple times. (I actually have a pretty good grasp on gradient boosting at this point with line search being the only piece escaping me.)

Comment: Maybe http://stats.stackexchange.com is better suited for this question

Answer (score 0):

The implementation is depending on which loss function you choose when initialize a `GradientBoostingClassifier` instance(use this for example, the regression part should be similar). The default loss function is ['deviance'](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.GradientBoostingClassifier.html) and the corresponding optimization algorithm is implemented [here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/4d9a12d175a38f2bcb720389ad2213f71a3d7697/sklearn/ensemble/gradient_boosting.py#L466). In the `_update_terminal_region` function, a simple Newton iteration is implemented with only one step.

Is this the answer you want?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the thing you find confusing is this: you can see where scikit-learn computes the negative gradient of the loss function and fits a base estimator to that negative gradient.  It looks like the `_update_terminal_region` method is responsible for figuring out the step size, but you can't see anywhere it might be solving the line search minimization problem as written in the documentation.

The reason you can't find a line search happening is that, for the special case of decision tree regressors, which are just piecewise constant functions, the optimal solution is usually known.  For example, if you look at the `_update_terminal_region` method of the  `LeastAbsoluteError` loss function, you see that the leaves of the tree are given the value of the weighted median of the difference between `y` and the predicted value for the examples for which that leaf is relevant.  This median is the known optimal solution.

To summarize what's happening, for each gradient descent iteration the following steps are taken:

1. Compute the negative gradient of the loss function at the current prediction.
2. Fit a `DecisionTreeRegressor` to the negative gradient.  This fitting produces a tree with good splits for decreasing the loss.
3. Replace the values at the leaves of the `DecisionTreeRegressor` with values that minimize loss.  These are usually computed from some simple known formula that takes advantage of the fact that the decision tree is just a piecewise constant function.

This method should be at least as good as what is described in the docs, but I think in some cases might not be identical to it.

Answer (score 0):

From your comments it seems the algorithm itself is unclear and not the way scikitlearn implements it.

Notation in the wikipedia article is slightly sloppy, one does not simply differentiate by a function evaluated at a point. Once you replace `F_{m-1}(x_i)` with `\hat{y_i}` and replace partial derivative with a partial derivative evaluated at `\hat{y}=F_{m-1}(x)` things become clearer:

[image]

This would also remove `x_{i}` (sort of) from the minimization problem and shows the intent of line search - to optimize depending on the current prediction and not depending on the training set. Now, notice that:

[image]

Hence you're just minimizing:

[image]

So line search simply optimizes one degree of freedom you have (once you've found the right gradient direction) - the step size.